# Query associated values

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a User model and a City model connected with a join table (has_and_belongs_to). So now when I want to display all the cities that a user chose, I think I should be able to make an iteration like @user.cities.each do |city| and then city.name. The problem now is that it displays an array with all the values of the raw.

I'm unable to get to the value of the "name" key unless I specify the position of the city like

```
cities.first.name 
cities.second.name
```

Which won't be practical if I want to display the names of a lot of cities. How can I iterate through this array and be able to specify the value that I want to display?

Comment: Shouldn't be `city.name` within the block?. Also `@user.cities.pluck(:name)` would give you an array with only city names.

Comment: Thank you Sebastian. The method pluck is what I'm looking for.